# Re-rendering react-redux component

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage

I am using react-redux code structure and this is my first try with react-redux.I have cloned a github repository [from Here](https://github.com/Agontuk/schema-designer) and started editing it.

My directory structure:

[image]

Here schema is parent component and header and tables are 2 child components.Tables is showing data from localstorage through redux store.

**Initializing store:**

```
 const initialState = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('test'));
 const store = createStore(Reducers, initialState, compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), extension));
```

Now an event is triggered from Header and sent to schema and in the response of this event schema is updating localstorage by requesting to server and saving server's response in localstorage as follows:

**Schema.js:**

```
class Schema extends PureComponent {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.table = ''; 
    getTables();       
}
myCallback = () => {//triggered by child(Header)
   getTables();       
}
getTables = () => {
  axios.get(url)
        .then((response) => {
            if(response.data.status==0){ 
 window.localStorage.setItem('test',JSON.stringify(response.data));
   this.tables=JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('test'))
    });
}
render() {
 console.log(this.tables);//this is giving updated value at each updation
    return (
        <div className='container-fluid'>
            <Header callbackFromParent={ this.myCallback } />
            <br />
            <br />
            <Tables val={ this.tables } />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is code for **Tables.js:**

```
   class Tables extends Component {
   props: Props
   render() {
   let {tables,val } = this.props;
   console.log(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('test')));//this is giving updated value at each updation in localstorage
   console.log(val);//this is also giving updated value at each updation in localstorage
   tables=val;
   console.log(tables);this is also updating in realtime.      
   return (
        <div className='table-wrapper'>
            { tables.map((table) => (
                <Table
                    key={ table.id }
                    data={ table }
                />
            ))}
        </div>
       );
     }
   }

   type Props = {
     tables: Array<TableType>
   };
```

The issue is whenever header triggers callback, schema updates value of localstorage, this updation also re render Tables component. Also an updated value can be seen in render of Tables component but the tables which are shown are from previous saved value. To get current value in tables, we need to refresh the page.

is it a mistake in code flow or i need something else for this?

Comment: **Note:**  
https://github.com/Agontuk/schema-designer/issues/2     This Issue also relates to my question where updating localstorage isnt updating component.

Comment: not sure it's directly related to your problem but i recommend that you should not do ajax requests (`getTables();`) in the `constructor` and instead do them in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: tried this but not working.I think a change/fix is needed in Tables component.

Comment: How is your Tables and Schema component getting re-rendered?
There is no change in the props or state.

Comment: because here <Tables val={ this.tables } /> value of this.tables is changing everytime.

Comment: You must update props or state for a component to re-render. Use `this.setState({tables: JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('test'))})` and `<Tables val={ this.state.tables } />`

Comment: i have tried this too.actually schema component is re rendering Tables component.you can see in Tables.js data is updating everytime in Tables.js render function.but the return portion in render function in Tables.js isnt updating.

Comment: are you sure the `render()` of Tables.js is being called each time i.e. are all console loggings showing up ?

Comment: yes all these consoles are logging correctly.its been week m trying on it.as far as i can guess its issue with redux.

Comment: Also, PureComponent is a premature optimization. Extend Component.

Comment: Changed it to Component but no change in results.

Comment: console.log is lying to you. It prints based on the reference of `this.tables` and its value changes after render has returned. Again, if you use and change state the component will re-render. By the way, you're not setting Redux state in this example so Redux has nothing to do with it.

Comment: yes m nt updating redux state here but it is showing the data stored in redux state.as if i refresh page the initialState stores data in redux state so it is shown in tables.

Comment: it is true that tables' value is changing after it is rendered and this is the issue.i want to re render it.how to achieve this?

Comment: As noted 4 times - updating state or props will cause a re-render. Don't use instance variables: `this.tables`. Simplify your example or play around with React to understand how it works.

Comment: Please use `this.state` as component re-rendering is based on that. Use `this.setState` to update  the state. If you follow this, you shouldn't face any issue. `this.tables` is not a good way.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that react will trigger rendering of component whenever the component `state` or `props` is updated.

If the component `props` are updated in parent component you will still need to update the component `state` to make the next render in inner component

The key of this is using `componentWillReceiveProps`

I updated your code with the code below:

Basically i did the following:

1- I used component state for `Schema`, `Tables`, and `Table`

2- I used `this.setState` whenever i need to make updates to state (this is very important)

3- I make sure that when a component `props` is updated in parent i update the component state as well using `componentWillReceiveProps` and this will make the new render with updated data

Schema component:

```
class Schema extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { tables : { } }
        this.getTables = this.getTables.bind(this);
        this.myCallback  = this.myCallback.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.getTables();
    }


    myCallback = () => {
       //triggered by child(Header)
       this.getTables();
    }


    getTables = () => {
      axios.get(url)
      .then((response) => {
            if(response.data.status==0)
            {
                window.localStorage.setItem('test',JSON.stringify(response.data));
                this.setState({
                    tables : JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('test'))
                });
            }
        );
    }


    render() {
        //this is giving updated value at each updation
        console.log(this.state.tables);
        return (
            <div className='container-fluid'>
                <Header callbackFromParent={ this.myCallback } />
                <br />
                <br />
                <Tables tables={this.state.tables} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Tables Component

```
 class Tables extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { tables : { }  }
    }


    componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({
            tables : this.props.tables
        })
    }


    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        this.setState({
            tables : nextProps.tables
        })
    }


   render() {
        console.log(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('test')));//this is giving updated value at each updation in localstorage
        console.log(this.state.tables);//this is also giving updated value at each updation in localstorage
       return (
            <div className='table-wrapper'>
                { this.state.tables.map((table) => (
                    <Table key={ table.id } data={ table } />
                ))
                }
            </div>
           );
    }
}
```

And finally a dummy Table component to show that you will also need to handle props update using `componentWillReceiveProps` to make sure each individual table component did render after `props` update

And probably this is where you have the issue ... because the tables are showing old data but the `console.log` of `Tables` component is logging new data which means Each individual `Table` component is not rending after the update

```
 class Table extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data : { }  }
    }


    componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({
            data : this.props.data
        })
    }


    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        this.setState({
            data : nextProps.data
        })
    }


   render() {
       console.log(this.state.data);
       return (
            <table className='table'>
                {this.state.data}
                //use your table data here
            </table>
           );
    }
}
```

Important Edit:

As mentioned by react documentation `componentWillReceiveProps` might get called even if the props have not changed, thats why in some situation you might need to consider comparing `this.props` with `nextProps` to make sure that you really got new updated `props` and based on that you update the component `state` ....

Comment: Thanx for a detailed answer.I tried this solution.now this.state.tables in schema.s is updating and it also triggering componentWillReceiveProps form Tables.js.but here nextProps is giving the same previous value.means componentWillReceiveProps is called everytime a change occurs but not updating the value.

Comment: One more thing i tried is i gave localstorage value directly in componenetWillRecieveProps.now in render method it is giving updated value everytime but rendered component is giving previous value still.same issue that render returned before state is updated.

Comment: you are welcome ..... ```componentWillReceiveProps```  might be called without props changes .... but i am sure that if  ```props``` changed it will be called as well with ```nextProps``` (updated) this is why react has this function .... Just make sure that you are passing the correct ```props``` and note that in the answer code i changed some props names like  ```<Tables val={ this.tables } />``` to  ```<Tables tables={ this.state.tables } />```  ..... also in ```Tables``` component i used only ```this.state.tables ``` and removed ```val``` as well

Comment: yes i noticed this change and updated my code accordingly.  I cant understand  why  componentWillReceiveProps     is called without props change while m giving updated props through this.state.tables in schema.js.